# getting error message for a return value from a mocked function

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mocking

I have this Dart code which uses Equatable and Oxidized packages:

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:oxidized/oxidized.dart';

abstract class Failure {}

class NumberTriviaEntity extends Equatable {
  final int number;
  final String text;
  
  const NumberTriviaEntity({required this.number, required this.text});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [text,number];
}

abstract interface class NumberTriviaIntf {
  Future<Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>> getConcreteNumberTrivia(int number);
  Future<Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>> getRandomNumberTrivia();
}

final class ConcreteNumberUseCase {
  final NumberTriviaIntf repository;

  const ConcreteNumberUseCase(this.repository);

  Future<Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>> execute({required int number}) async {
    return await repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number);
  }
}
```

I'm making a test on NumberTriviaIntf interface by using Mockito package:

```dart
class MockNumberTriviaIntf extends Mock implements NumberTriviaIntf {}
class MockFailure extends Mock implements Failure {}

void main() {
  group('ConcreteNumberUseCase', () {
    late MockNumberTriviaIntf repository;
    late ConcreteNumberUseCase useCase;
    
    setUp(() {
      repository = MockNumberTriviaIntf();
      useCase = ConcreteNumberUseCase(repository);
    });

    test('returns Ok with valid data', () async {
      // Arrange
      const number = 42;
      const Result<NumberTriviaEntity,Failure> entity = Ok(NumberTriviaEntity(number: number, text: 'Santi-U'));
      when(repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number)).thenAnswer((_) async => entity);
      // Act
      final result = await useCase.execute(number: number);
      // Assert
      expect(result, entity);
      verify(repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number));
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(repository);
    });

    test('returns Err with failure', () async {
      // Arrange
      const number = 43;
      final Result<NumberTriviaEntity,Failure> error = Err(MockFailure());
    });
  });
}
```

but I always get the following error message on this line: `when(repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number)).thenAnswer((_) async => entity)`

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>>'
MockNumberTriviaIntf.getConcreteNumberTrivia
main.<fn>.<fn>

✖ ConcreteNumberUseCase returns Ok with valid data
✓ ConcreteNumberUseCase returns Err with failure
Exited (1)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: If you're using `package:mockito` with null safety, you should be doing a code generation step ([or implementing mocks manually](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md)), and I don't see you using `@GenerateNiceMocks`/`@GenerateMocks`.  Follow the instructions from the [`README`](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito).

Comment: instead of mocked classes I'm using now `@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<NumberTriviaIntf>(), MockSpec<Failure>()])`, but I'm getting a new error: `MissingDummyValueError: Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>. This means Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type
'Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>'. Please consider using either 'provideDummy' or 'provideDummyBuilder'
functions to give Mockito a proper dummy value.
`. There's no help about how to use **provideDummy** or **provideDummyBuilder**

Comment: Did you read the API documentation for [`provideDummy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/provideDummy.html)/[`provideDummyBuilder`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/provideDummyBuilder.html)?  Basically just call `provideDummy` with whatever you want the default value of `Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>` to be.

Comment: I already read them but they don't help me much. I would ask you something, because it seems you are clear about how to solve the problem, could you post your response with the changes that are required?

Comment: Again, call `provideDummy` without whatever you want the default value to be for an object of type `Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>`.  Or perhaps try using `@GenerateMocks` instead of `@GenerateNiceMocks`.

Comment: For example: `provideDummy(Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>.err(MockFailure()));`

Answer (score 0):

First off, my thanks to @jamesdlin for his help. Here the solution (for Mockito 5.4.2, Dart 3.1.3):

```dart
@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<NumberTriviaIntf>(), MockSpec<Failure>()])
import 'concrete_number_usecase_test.mocks.dart';

typedef TriviaEntityResult = Result<NumberTriviaEntity,Failure>;

void main() {
  group('ConcreteNumberUseCase', () {
    late MockNumberTriviaIntf repository;
    late ConcreteNumberUseCase useCase;
    
    setUp(() {
      repository = MockNumberTriviaIntf();
      useCase = ConcreteNumberUseCase(repository);
      provideDummy(Result<NumberTriviaEntity, Failure>.err(MockFailure()));
    });

    // Helper method for verification
    void verifyExecute(int number, TriviaEntityResult result, TriviaEntityResult expectedResult) {
      expect(result, expectedResult);
      verify(repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number));
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(repository);
    }

    test('returns Ok with valid data', () async {
      // Arrange
      const number = 42;
      const TriviaEntityResult expectedResult = Ok(NumberTriviaEntity(number: number, text: 'Santi-U'));
      when(repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => expectedResult);
      // Act
      final result = await useCase(number: number);
      // Assert
      verifyExecute(number, result, expectedResult);
    });

    test('returns Err with failure', () async {
      // Arrange
      const number = 43;
      final TriviaEntityResult error = Err(MockFailure());
      when(repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => error);
      // Act
      final result = await useCase(number: number);
      // Assert
      verifyExecute(number, result, error);
    });
  });
}
```