# How can unit tests be created for a method that returns a Sealed class as its return value?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

How should unit tests for a method that returns a Sealed class like the following be created?

```dart
sealed class Result<S, E extends Exception> {
  const Result();
}

final class Success<S, E extends Exception> extends Result<S, E> {
  const Success({required this.value});
  final S value;
}

final class Failure<S, E extends Exception> extends Result<S, E> {
  const Failure({required this.exception});
  final E exception;
}

extension ResultExtension on Result<dynamic, Exception> {
  dynamic get unwrap => switch (this) {
        Success() => (this as Success).value,
        Failure() => throw (this as Failure).exception,
      };
}
```

When creating and running unit tests for a method that returns a Sealed class, such as the Result class, the following error occurs:

```dart
 MissingDummyValueError: Result<void, Exception>
  
  This means Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type
  'Result<void, Exception>'. Please consider using either 'provideDummy' or 'provideDummyBuilder'
  functions to give Mockito a proper dummy value.
  
  Please note that due to implementation details Mockito sometimes needs users
  to provide dummy values for some types, even if they plan to explicitly stub
  all the called methods.
```

I couldn't find anyone creating unit tests for a method that returns a Sealed Class as a return value, even after doing some research. How should unit tests for a method that returns a sealed class as a return value be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First a note on terminology: You aren't unit testing a method that returns a sealed class. To create unit tests for such a method, you simply call that method and verify that its return values match what you expect for given inputs. What you're asking about is how to *mock* a method that returns a sealed class.  That is, the method itself isn't being tested; you're testing *other* functions to verify how they interact with that method. Your question is about `package:mockito`, not about unit tests.
2. The error message tells you what to do: call `provideDummy` with whatever you want the default value for a `Result<void, Exception>` to be.  Since it's a "dummy" value, the value you choose shouldn't matter.  For example:

   ```dart
   @GenerateNiceMocks([...])
   void main() {
     provideDummy(Result<void, Exception>());

     // ... Code to run tests...
   }
   ```

   Also see [getting error message for a return value from a mocked function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77205684).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are there any websites that explain how to use "provideDummy"? Also, where did Jamesdlin learn how to use it? I couldn't find any websites that explain how to use "provideDummy" when searching for it.

Comment: @sub I simply figured it out from the [`provideDummy` API documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/provideDummy.html).  It's fairly straightforward once you understand the purpose of the function: to provide a default value when needed for a non-nullable type.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/697

Comment: In Jamesdlin's response, the line provideDummy(Result<void, Exception>.err(Exception())); actually resulted in an error.

The class 'Result' doesn't have a constructor named 'err'.
Try invoking a different constructor, or define a constructor named 'err'.

Comment: @sub Sorry, I was assuming that you were using the same `Result` class as from the linked question, which used `Result` from `package:oxidized`.  In your case, it's even simpler: `provideDummy(Result<void, Exception>())` or `provideDummy(Failure<void, Exception>(exception: Exception()))`, depending on your preference.  Again, the point is to provide a default value for an object of type `Result<void, Exception>`, so just create *some* value and pass it to `provideDummy`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but 
`provideDummy(const Success<void, Exception>(value: null));`and,
`provideDummy(Failure<void, Exception>(exception: UserNotFoundException()));`


I tried defining it, but even after defining it, the error is still being thrown.

Comment: @sub Oops. `provideDummy` will infer the type from the argument, and the type needs to match what's reported by the error message exactly, so you'd need to explicitly specify the type.  That is, `provideDummy(Failure<void, Exception>(...))` would need to be `provideDummy<Result<void, Exception>>(Failure<void, Exception>(...))`.  You're better off just using `provideDummy(Result<void, Exception>())`.

Comment: I successfully used 'provideDummy<Result<void, Exception>>(Failure<void, Exception>(...))'! Thank you very much. I'm extremely grateful. Thank you.