# How can I mock the function [Flutter Mockito]

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito, bloc, either

I have method in api

```
  Future<Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto>> signIn({
     required final String login,
     required final String password,
 }) async {
   final data = await _apiDataProvider.signIn(login: login, password: password);
   if (data.isLeft) {
     return Left(ApiErrorDto.fromApi(apiError: data.left));
   }
   return Right(AuthSignInDto.fromApi(response: data.right));
}
```

I use it in AuthBloc

```
 FutureOr<void> _onAuthPageSignIn(
     final AuthPageSignIn event, final Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
   final data = await api.signIn(
      login: event.login,
      password: event.password);
   if (data.isRight) {
      emit(AuthDoneState());
   } else {
      emit(AuthErrorState(apiError: data.left));
   }
}
```

I try to write the unit test on this

```
blocTest<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
  "Auth BLoC's emit AuthDoneState() when api request happens successfully ",
  build: () {
    when(api.signIn(login: '', password: '')).thenAnswer((_) =>
        Future<Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto>>.value(const Right(
            AuthSignInDto(token: 'token', username: 'username'))));
    return authBloc;
  },
  act: (bloc) {
    bloc.add(const AuthPageSignIn(login: 'admin', password: 'admin'));
  },
  expect: () => <AuthState>[
    AuthDoneState(),
  ],
);
```

I get the error

> MissingDummyValueError: Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto>
>
> This means Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type
> 'Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto>'. Please consider using either 'provideDummy' or 'provideDummyBuilder'
> functions to give Mockito a proper dummy value.
>
> Please note that due to implementation details Mockito sometimes needs users
> to provide dummy values for some types, even if they plan to explicitly stub
> all the called methods.

How can I provide dummyvalue for Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto> ?

Comment: The message tells you what you do: call `provideDummy` with a dummy value for `Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto>`.  For example: `provideDummy(Either<ApiErrorDto, AuthSignInDto>())`.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77272908/